# How to disable forward, backward button when there is no more routes in history in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, vue-router

Hi my app runs as a plugin inside another application so i have to handle `forward,backward` navigation manually.

**My Question:** i want to disable `forward`, `backward` button with `.disabled` class when there is no more route.

Any way i'm using history mode for going forward i'm using `go(1)` and for going backward i'm using `go(-1)`

**Here are the steps to see my points:**

1. click on `Browse ++` button  3 times
2. now click on `<` 3 times at 3rd time it must be disabled
3. now click on `>` 3 times at 3rd time it must be disabled

here is my code link

https://codesandbox.io/s/path-traversing-w6yy3f

Comment: You should override `VueRouter.push` and `VueRouter.go` and keep your own `stack` of visited routes inside Vuex. Then, when the stack is empty - you can detect this and apply the required CSS class(es). Just handling the `window.popstate` event won't be enough because it s only fired on clicking the browsers BACK and FORWARD buttons - but not when calling `history.pushState` or `history.replaceState`

Answer (score 1):

> I want to disable forward, backward button with .disabled class when
> there is no more route.

*Div's can't be disabled.* as you have `div` element for both backward and forward clicks.

Hence, For now I am removing the `backward` and `forward` div from the DOM as per the condition using `v-if`.

Working Demo **:** https://codesandbox.io/s/path-traversing-forked-dq3dte

Comment: Your code seems to be working !! , i need to test it with more test cases, still 2 days are remaining + grace period

Comment: @EaBengaluru Sure. I am glad that it works as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

https://codesandbox.io/s/path-traversing-forked-djjbeb

unfortunately there is no way to get the current position you are on the browser history, so we need to track it somewhere.

This solution would only work however if the navigation happens trough your links, it does not work if the browser navigation is used.

**EDIT**

Fixed the issue with the console errors on opensandbox. The culprit was the :

```
 created() {
    console.log("thiss", this.$route);
  },
```

removing the console.log stops the log errors.

You can read and track the bug here
https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/2095#issuecomment-818500869

Comment: It's not working. Giving error on click of forward and backward icons

Comment: So it looks like there is a bug on opensandbox https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/2095#issuecomment-818500869.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to store a variable referencing the current index and increment/decrement it when you navigate forward/backward.

```
backward() {
  currentIndex--;
  this.$router.go(-1);
},

forward() {
  currentIndex++;
  this.$router.go(1);
},
browse() {
  const param = this.getRandomTraversingObject();
  this.$router.push({ name: "traverse", params: param });
  console.log(this.$router, this.$router.history.length);
  currentIndex++;
},
```

Then just bind the `.disabled` class to currentIndex...

Comment: It will work in disable the `backward` button if `currentIndex = 0` but not in the `forward` case.

Comment: You can use window.history.length for the forward button, or keep track of the total length in a separate variable.